# VBA Textbox event to call private userform function

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to create an userform that have a textbox field and, at runtime, i'll be able to add how many more boxes I need.

For now, I've created a button that does that, but I want it to automatically create the new field just pressing the '+' key while in the box.

I found out that I can create a custom class module to handle all the new boxes I'm creating, but I'm not able to make this class call the function that creates the next ones.

How do I say to my program "every time I hit the +, you create a new box"?

What I've got so far is this

**clsObjHandler class module:**

```
Public WithEvents txtBoxCustom As MSForms.TextBox

Private Sub txtBoxCustom_KeyPress(ByVal KeyAscii As MSForms.ReturnInteger)
    If KeyAscii = 43 Then
        createNewBox
        KeyAscii = 0
    End If
End Sub
```

**UserForm module:**

```
Option Explicit
Dim colTbxs As Collection

Public Function createNewBox()
    Dim newField As Control
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim clsObject As clsObjHandler

    i = Me.Frame1.Controls.count

    Set newField = Me.Frame1.Controls.Add("Forms.TextBox.1", "SESPO" & i)

    newField.name = "SESPO" & i
    newField.Left = 12
    newField.Top = insertLineBtn.Top + 18
    insertLineBtn.Top = insertLineBtn.Top + 18
    insertPoForm.Height = insertPoForm.Height + 18
    Frame1.Height = Frame1.Height + 18
    insertPosBtn.Top = insertPosBtn.Top + 18
    newField.SetFocus

    Set clsObject = New clsObjHandler
    Set clsObject.txtBoxCustom = newField
    colTbxs.Add clsObject
    Set clsObject = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Good you solved it, so post it as an answer and wait to see if you will get batter answer also don't add title [solved]

Answer (score 0):

I solved using the Application.Run on the class module. Dont know if it's the best approach, but it worked. Like this:

```
Public WithEvents txtBoxCustom As MSForms.TextBox

Private Sub txtBoxCustom_KeyPress(ByVal KeyAscii As MSForms.ReturnInteger)
    If KeyAscii = 43 Then
        Application.Run UserForm.createNewBox
        KeyAscii = 0
    End If
End Sub
```